# How to show column record if it matched with another table record using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am searching record by column, if it match with anyone of column,it has to show the entire column record in row.

This question is similarly same to my previous question. but there is some changes,that i cannot get the result

Here is my table

**RelationData**

```
Parent    child1    child2    child3
------------------------------------
111       112       113       117
111       222       223       224
444       441       442       443 
333       331       332       334
888       887       889       885
```

**#tempRecord**

```
ItemID
-----
112
443 
888
```

I wants to get entire row of parent,if the `#tempRecord.ItemID` is matched with anyone of the column in `RelationData`

**Expecting output**

```
ItemID
------
111
112
113 
117
222
223
224   
        //111 is the parent of two row. so it will show 2 rows records
444
441
442
443 
888
887
889  
885
```

I tried this following query with the help of Mr.GordonLinoff

```
SELECT 
    v.child ItemID
FROM 
    RelationData rd outer apply
       (values (rd.ID),(rd.ChildID1), (rd.ChildID2), (rd.childID3)) v(child)
 INNER JOIN ItemTable Item on item.id = v.child 
LEFT JOIN #tempData tt on item.id = tt.Itemid
WHERE
    (SELECT Itemid FROM #tempData) IN (rd.ID, rd.ChildID1, rd.ChildID2, rd.childID3) 
    and v.child is not null
GROUP BY v.child
```

Comment: Your query has something called `itemTable` but it is not part of your question.  It seems superfluous based on the results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry i will remove. I try someother as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this version:

```
SELECT v.child as ItemID
FROM RelationData rd OUTER APPLY
       (VALUES (rd.ID), (rd.ChildID1), (rd.ChildID2), (rd.childID3)
       ) v(child) JOIN
      #tempData tt 
      ON tt.Itemid IN (rd.ID, rd.ChildID1, rd.ChildID2, rd.childID3) 
WHERE v.child IS NOT NULL;
```

If you don't want duplicates, use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: you may leave the item table. Take only RelationData and #tempData table

Answer (score 0):

Hm... if it's always only three childs, it can be solved quite straight forward:

```
DECLARE @tRelation TABLE(
  parent int
 ,child1 int
 ,child2 int
 ,child3 int
)

INSERT INTO @tRelation VALUES
 (111       ,112       ,113       ,117)
,(111       ,222       ,223       ,224)
,(444       ,441       ,442       ,443) 
,(333       ,331       ,332       ,334)
,(888       ,887       ,889       ,885)

;WITH cte AS(
  SELECT parent, parent AS child
    FROM @tRelation
  UNION
  SELECT parent, child1 AS child
    FROM @tRelation
  UNION
  SELECT parent, child2 AS child
    FROM @tRelation
  UNION
  SELECT parent, child3 AS child
    FROM @tRelation
)
SELECT child
  FROM cte
  WHERE parent = 111
```

Another approach might be using UNPIVOT, but here you will have to add (via Union or whatever) the parent in order to be outoutted as well:

```
SELECT parent, child
  FROM
  (SELECT parent, child1, child2, child3
    FROM @tRelation) c
  UNPIVOT
  (child FOR childno in (child1, child2, child3)
  ) AS chlds
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to unpivot based on the solution by Tyron78. Basically I finished both his versions - and the unpivot-version performs better. Nice one!

Setup test data:

```
DECLARE @tRelation TABLE(
  parent int
 ,child1 int
 ,child2 int
 ,child3 int
)
declare @tempRecord table(ItemId int)

INSERT INTO @tRelation VALUES
 (111       ,112       ,113       ,117)
,(111       ,222       ,223       ,224)
,(444       ,441       ,442       ,443) 
,(333       ,331       ,332       ,334)
,(888       ,887       ,889       ,885)

insert into @tempRecord(ItemId)
values(112), (443), (888)
```

First solution with union and CTE:

```
;WITH cte(parent, child) AS(
    SELECT parent, parent AS child
    FROM @tRelation
    union
    SELECT parent, child1 AS child
    FROM @tRelation
    UNION
    SELECT parent, child2 AS child
    FROM @tRelation
    UNION
    SELECT parent, child3 AS child
    FROM @tRelation
)

SELECT      cteChild.child
FROM        cte
            inner join
            @tempRecord tempRecord
            on  tempRecord.ItemId = cte.child
            inner join
            cte cteChild
            on  cteChild.parent = cte.parent
```

Second solution with unpivot:

```
SELECT      child
FROM        (
                SELECT      tRelation.parent,
                            tRelationSameParent.child1,
                            tRelationSameParent.child2,
                            tRelationSameParent.child3
                FROM        @tRelation tRelation
                            inner join
                            @tempRecord tempRecord
                            on  tempRecord.ItemId in (
                                    tRelation.parent,
                                    tRelation.child1,
                                    tRelation.child2,
                                    tRelation.child3)
                            inner join
                            @tRelation tRelationSameParent
                            on  tRelationSameParent.parent = tRelation.parent
            ) c
            UNPIVOT
            (child FOR childno in (parent, child1, child2, child3) ) AS chlds
```

Teh second one preforms better and is nicer.